# git clone - слишком много аргументов

Tags: linux, git, shell, git-clone

Не работает команда гита:

```
git clone -b $(curl -L https://grpc.io/release) https://github.com/grpc/grpc
```

Взял её вот отсюда: [github_link](https://github.com/IvanSafonov/grpc-cmake-example)

говорит что неверный синтаксис, как исправить не понимаю:

```
root@user:/opt# git clone -b $(curl -L https://grpc.io/release) https://github.com/grpc/grpc
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 27038    0 27038    0     0  64684      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 64529
fatal: Слишком много аргументов.

использование: git clone [<опции>] [--] <репозиторий> [<каталог>]

    -v, --verbose         быть многословнее
    -q, --quiet           тихий режим
    --progress            принудительно выводить прогресс
    -n, --no-checkout     не переключать рабочую копию на HEAD
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Разберем, из чего состоит команда, и как исправить.

- `git clone -b` - клонировать бранчу с названием ...
- `$(curl -L https://grpc.io/release)` - название бранчи

Получается, что по указанному адресу должно отдаваться название бранчи. Но его нет, и там 404 ошибка. Почему? Потому что это сломалось. Напишите автору через issue, чтобы поправил

Мейнтейнер через `$(curl -L https://grpc.io/release)` сделал получение последнего релиза. Но эта часть сломалась. Посмотрим, какие [ветки есть в проекте](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/branches). Там их много, выберите ту, что вам нравится. Последняя - `v1.39.x`.

Что вам нужно? Поправьте `-b ...`, получится `git clone -b v1.39.x https://github.com/grpc/grpc`.

А чтобы следующий раз понимать, что делает такая сложная команда, введите в консоли `set -x`, а затем команды. Активируется дебаг режим, который покажет, что вообще происходит. В данном случае выполнялась белиберда:

```
git clone -b '<!doctype' 'html><html' lang=en ... ... ...
```

Comment: Все правильно, кроме, того, что `там только master`. Там много версий на самом деле https://github.com/grpc/grpc/branches

Comment: @RomanKonoval да, посмотрел по другой ссылке

Comment: @TotalPusher ещё такой вопрос, в конце, последняя команда 
`sudo make prefix=/opt/grpc install`
выдает вот такую ошибку: 
  `root@l78-m:/opt/grpc# sudo make prefix=/opt/grpc install`

  `Installing via 'make' is no longer supported. Use cmake or bazel instead.`

  `Please consult BUILDING.md to get more information.`

  `make: *** [Makefile:707: stop] Ошибка 1`

Comment: @lbsmart нужно использовать cmake, подробности в BUILDING.md, пройдите по всем шагам, там все написано. Если не получится, создайте отдельный вопрос на SO, так по правилам. Плюс на гитхабе указано, что релиз v1.39.0. Это значит нужно клонировать ветку v1.39.x (это вы сделали), а затем сделать git checkout v1.39.0 - так будет переключение по тегу, и это будет именно релиз, а не самый последний код. Релиз - это готовый протестированный код.